# Problem with npm start. react. internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, module, npm-start

i cannot run server. i just made all data but there is something wrong.
i attached code on github
what can be wrong ?

https://github.com/siemacotam/project_shop

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\project_shop\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\project_shop\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
```

Comment: Since webpack is missing, have you tried to `npm install -D webpack`? Or you might also just try to delete the `node_modules` directory entirely and do a fresh `npm install`, since it's a dependency of `webpack-dev-server`. Maybe the dependencies are corrupted

Comment: I did npm install -D webpack right now and the error change to


internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'